# How to use for loop counter with a nested if loop?

Tags: python, django

I created a for loop with a nested if statement for counting specific types of customers in my Django project. What I need is the final number of the `for loop counter`.

I try:

```
{% if forloop.last %}
    {{ forloop.counter }}
{% endif %}
```

But it displays nothing. But when try just `{{ forloop.counter }}` it displays 2 number. One of them is what I want but the other one is all for loops I think.

How can I solve this problem?

**list.html**

```
{% for customer in customer_list %}
   {% if customer.country.country_name == country %}
      {% if customer.risk_rating == "Low Risk" %}
          {% if forloop.last %}
             {{ forloop.counter }}
          {% endif %}
       {% endif %}
   {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

**views.py**

```
def test_customer_list(request):
    current_user = request.user
    userP = UserProfile.objects.get_or_create(username=current_user)
    customer_list = Customer.objects.filter(company=userP[0].company)
    countries = Customer.objects.values_list('country__country_name', flat=True).distinct()
    country_links = Country.objects.filter()
    context = {
        'customer_list': customer_list,
        'countries': countries,
        'country_links': country_links
    }

    return render(request, 'test.html', context)

class Country(models.Model):
    REGION = [
        ('Northwest Europe', 'Northwest Europe'),
        ('Southwest Europe', 'Southwest Europe'),
        ('CIS', 'CIS'),
        ('MENA', 'MENA'),
        ('APAC', 'APAC'),
        ('North America', 'North America'),
        ('South America', 'South America'),

    ]

    country_name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    country_code = models.CharField(max_length=5)
    country_flag = models.ImageField(upload_to='profile_image', blank=True, null=True)
    country_info = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    region = models.CharField(max_length=50, default='Select', choices=REGION, null=True)
    coface_rating = models.CharField(max_length=5)
    coface_explanation = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    sp_rating = models.CharField(max_length=5)
    sp_explanation = models.CharField(max_length=200)
```

Comment: That won't work that way, the for loop still iterates over _all_ objects. The `if`'s for `country_name` and `risk_rating` are then just filtering out in the template, and hence your `{% if forloop.last %}{{ forloop.counter }}{% endif %}` might not even be called, probably the last customer in the for loop doesn't match your conditions and hence you don't see the output. Three questions: 1) All you want is the number of customers matching those queries? 2) Why don't you do the counting then in the view? 3) Where does `country` come from?

Comment: I want to count how many low, medium, etc risk customers in the customer list, yes. I cannot figure out how can I do that in views added. And I added the Country model.

Answer (score 0):

```
low_risk_count = Customer.objects.filter(company=UserP.company, risk_rating="Low Risk").count()
```

Comment: Every country has a different number of low risk, it should be change in every row of the table

Comment: I don't really understand what's your intended result of that query then.. Can you please try to make yourself clearer?